# CodeIgniter Active Record limit doesn't work with MSSQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, codeigniter

I was trying to return partial results and I was hoping that Active Record handles pagination manually since mssql doesn't support offsets. However the following code doesn't work as expected.

```
    public function get_companies($search,$start,$limit)
{
    $this->aws = $this->load->database('aws', TRUE);
    $this->aws->select('*');
    $this->aws->from('_companies');
    $this->aws->order_by("Company");
    **$this->aws->limit($start, $limit);** 
    $this->aws->like('Company', $search); 
    $query = $this->aws->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

Comment: At limit CI Active Record are different for Mysql and MSSql. Read this: http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/160626/. Maybe will help you.

Answer (score 1):

I have done code using limit and its working fine for me.

```
public function get_user_list($limit=0,$offset=0)
{
    $this->db->select('*');    

    if(isset($limit)&& $limit!='')    
    {        
        $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);     
    }

    $this->db->from(USER_TABLE_NAME);    

    if(isset($condition) && $condition != '')    
    {            
        $this->db->where($condition);        
    } 

    $this->db->order_by("firstname", "asc");     
    $query = $this->db->get();    
    echo $this->db->last_query();  // To Get Whole SQL Query  
    return $query->result_array();
```

}

**Best Of Luck**

Answer (score 1):

CodeIgniter from v2.2 ahead supports 100% the `limit()` method for all the drivers available.